# Best practice to make editable grid in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are porting our application from GWT to angular. In our application , we uses editable grid.

One way to make grid editable is to use separate editor each cell. Doing this a simple page with 4 columns and 100 rows takes 2000 ms to render.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FTaQBPOoaBtbHqgltF7r?p=preview

Another way to do this is to use only single editor in a absolute div and position this div on the selected td. But doing do may required dom calculation which is prohibited in angular. But it tooks only 500 ms to render

http://plnkr.co/edit/S0ivQ5yJSwx26M0tt2GX?p=preview

As I am new to angular, which approach should we follow.

Comment: Use ng-grid https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid

Comment: But there is not editable plnkr I found on that link. A link at http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ pointing to http://plnkr.co/edit/mfIWpK?p=preview say it is editable, but it was not

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `enableCellEdit: true` is missing in the plunkr.

Try this -> http://plnkr.co/edit/EzCZcM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Selvam, It is editable now. But it seems that it does not have data binding property working. When we double click, input box is empty. http://plnkr.co/edit/EzCZcM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:
http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable

there are demos with editable row / column and whole grid.

Comment: Hi, I have used angular-xeditable  in the past for my angularjs projects ( Especially - https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row)  For angular it looks like there is no version available. Is there any plan to release one for Angular. If not can you give pointers on how to achieve this using Angular. ( Also. Thanks for the AngularJS version. It was great and helped me immensely. )